# How to return the program flow at the beginning in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a `Player` class in my Ruby solution. In the class I can define two players. I need to make a validation and if the names of the players are the same, I need to throw a message about it and in case they are the same, I need to return my program to the beginning. Below is my code:

```
class Player
  print "First player, put your name then press ENTER: "
  name1 = gets.chomp
  print "Second player, put your name then press ENTER: "
  name2 = gets.chomp

  if name1.eql?(name2)
    abort "Put the different name for players!"
  end

end
```

Comment: Are you looking for a **loop**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a loop

```
name1 = name2 = nil
while name1 == name2
  print "First player, put your name then press ENTER: "
  name1 = gets.chomp
  print "Second player, put your name then press ENTER: "
  name2 = gets.chomp

  if name1 == name2
    print "Put the different name for players!"
  end
end
```

You can place it into an object, but as it is, your class has no sense at all. You defined a class, but then you put all the code into the body of the class without even wrapping it into a method.

It should be

```
class Player
  def play
    name1 = name2 = nil
    while name1 == name2
      print "First player, put your name then press ENTER: "
      name1 = gets.chomp
      print "Second player, put your name then press ENTER: "
      name2 = gets.chomp

      if name1 == name2
        print "Put the different name for players!"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And then you can call it without

```
player = Player.new
player.play
```

Comment: `gets` is defined in `Kernel`, which is `include`d in `Object`. It is *the* standard method for getting a string from standard input, taught in every introductory Ruby text.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I respect your replies, we have been reading each other since a long time. However, your comment seems to be very haughty. I haven't been writing an introductory "get char from keyboard" Ruby code in years... therefore I apologize if I don't recall the entire Ruby language by heart. I appreciate your comment, just try to not be that snob.

Answer (score 1):

```
begin
  print "First player, put your name then press ENTER: "
  name1 = gets.chomp
  print "Second player, put your name then press ENTER: "
  name2 = gets.chomp

  raise "Put the different name for players!" if name1 == name2
rescue => e
  puts e.message
  retry
end
```

Comment: You should not use exceptions to simulate a loop whenever you can use a loop, since exceptions are not cheap (in terms of memory and usage).